# How to create new <tr> in html from values returned by json_encode()?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, loops

I have JSON code:

```
echo json_encode(array(
        'sn' => $sn,
        'a' => $detail,
        'b' => $sector ));
```

I parse them like this:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
     $( '#sn' ).html(data.sn);
     $( '#a' ).html(data.a);
     $( '#b' ).html(data.b);
```

Here I can get arrays of data. I want to display these array values in (tr tag) rows. I want to display them in html code like this:

```
<tr><td>Sn</td>
<td>Detail</td>
<td>Sector</td></tr>
LOOP starts here to display values of array 
<tr><td><div id="sn"></div></td>
<td><div id="a"></div></td>
<td><div id="b"></div></td></tr>
LOOP ends here
```

Comment: add `php` tag to your question

Comment: how abt <script> ?

Comment: how about a downvote?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest 36 vs 5,391 reputation is not fair enough to down vote

Comment: not 5,391 but 5,931. I know, and I didn't downvote ... yet. It will depend on your behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key, value) {
  $('#' + data[key]).html(value);
});
```

But it would be better if your data was encoded differently

```
echo json_encode(array(
  array('selector'=>'sn', 'html'=>$sn),
  array('selector'=>'a', 'html'=>$detail),
  array('selector'=>'b', 'html'=>$sector)
));
```

Then

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
data.forEach(function(update) {
  $('#' + update.selector).html(update.html);
});
```

Comment: But I have to add a input text menu in every <tr>

Comment: how can I add <tr> and </td>